# Should we change "on hold" to "needs revision" or something similar?

Tags: discussion, on-hold

One thing that I like about the [Russian Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) site is how the community, in the process of discussing the translation of the site, has decided to reword some things to make them clearer and/or more diplomatic.

In particular, instead of [заморожен] (frozen) they opted for [требует правки] (needs editing). I think this is much nicer and makes it clearer to the person asking the question that there is some action they can perform to have it considered for reopening.

Should we do something similar on the English Stack Overflow? I feel like [on hold] is a little bit off-putting for new users and something along the lines of [needs revision] is more inviting to action.

Comment: Japanese is similar. Instead of 保留中 (on hold, like on the phone), we used 改善待ち (awaiting improvement).

Comment: I never liked "On Hold" anyway.  *"Your call is important to us... Please wait for the next available moderator.  [click]"*

Comment: I vote for *[Queued for deletion]*.

Comment: We once burned quite a few neurons [trying to find a better term](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173497/164403) on the Overmeta.

Comment: "Revision" seems like a pretty big word. How about "needs editing"?

Comment: I get that we want to encourage people editing their slightly unanswerable questions, but won't this also encourage people to waste time on and duplicate questions that are totally unsalvageable?

Comment: @Dukeling: Duplicate questions should remain "closed" or "put on hold."  To be fair, we already tell people at the bottom of the close reason to improve their question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean - they may duplicate the question because they think it's appropriate for the site but it was just missed by people able to answer because they edited it too late or something or that asking the edited version as a new question is better for whatever reason (and, just to reiterate, I'm talking about totally unsalvageable questions here). We can just close them again, sure, but it'd be wasting everyone's time.

Comment: There are several proposals in comment here. Shouldn't they be posted as answers instead to see if we can come to a consensus ?

Comment: This issue goes beyond the wording.  One or two "On Hold" votes doesn't stop the question from being answered.  (And it shouldn't) It doesn't stop the question from being answered in the comments section.  There are **TONS** of "On Hold" votes that never amount to anything.  The basic strategy is flawed.

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated to Meta.SE?

Comment: I would say "Pending Revision"

Comment: @M.Doye You can add that as an answer if you want.

Comment: @ruakh The text that displays on duplicates isn't relevant to my comments. What I'm referring to is the original question getting closed, but the asker thinking it was actually basically okay because of the displayed text and then duplicates it. Note that I said "waste time on **and** duplicate questions".

Comment: Yes. I see people flagging questions "On Hold" when they no way related to the domain. They are not bothered to remove the "On Hold" even after revising the question and providing more details. It is definitely frustrating

Comment: I love the innovation that we gain from the strong communities that have built around the non-english sites.

Comment: Going to resist editing the OP to include the fact that the *original* close messaged (at least, original as of me joining) used to say `Closed as . . .`.

Answer (score 56):

IMHO it would even be better if the text would adapt to the reason (majority of close reasons) why the question is on hold.

- "Unclear": [needs clarification]
- "Too broad": [needs constraints]
- "Opinion based": [needs concretion]
- "Duplicate": [duplicate] (like it is already)
- "Off topic": [needs scope adjustment]

Comment: Thoughts: not every closure _needs_ an action to be taken. E.g. all correctly identified dupes don't "need differentiation", they're simply dupes. Similarily, some "off topic" questions do not "need scope adjustment" but need to be migrated or deleted as they cannot ever fit the site. Issuing a call to action when the action is not always preferable seems like a bad idea (that's my beef with all "needs [something]" suggestions - many closed questions just need to be left alone to be autodeleted). Also, having that many different texts might cause confusion, especially for non-native speakers.

Comment: @PeterOlson: I'm not a native speaker. Maybe there's a better term than that.

Comment: @l4mpi: I'm not certain: are duplicates *[on hold]* before they are actually marked as *[duplicate]*? Above was expected to be a list of terms for *[on hold]*, not for *[duplicate]*. If there is no *[on hold]* for duplicate reason, then it should be removed from the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best word would be either. It's community wiki, so I guess somebody more creative than us can come up with a better alternative.

Comment: I think this answer is the best, but I'm also concerned about "scope adjustment". What about `[needs refocus]`? I think this would convey to new users that they need to *drastically* change questions, while other questions that are off-topic still fit under this category.

Comment: @ZX9 Objectify means something different entirely. https://www.google.com/search?q=objectify

Comment: I like the idea of @tinygiant 's [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298828/3745896) that we shouldn't have an extra tag for opinion based questions at all, as it is unlikely that they can be edited to make them SO appropriate.

Comment: `Needs concretion` sounds awful, and will not immediately convey the intent of the message.

Comment: There is one aspect here that is missed. Not every question which is closed can be saved. Statistically questions are reopened at a very low rate. No amount of editing will help most of them.

Answer (score 45):

The wording should be changed to "needs improvement".

Comment: This mix wasn't represented yet. I think it captures the intent better than undirected "editing" or passive "awaiting".

Comment: Hmm. [Seems familiar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298683/should-we-change-on-hold-to-needs-revision-or-something-similar/298741#298741). (You did post this before my answer was decided, but it's still worth noting.)

Comment: Hah, at least the community's consistent :-p

Comment: Lol, there's a reason I deferred this to (at least partially) non-programmers. ;)

Answer (score 38):

The wording should be changed to "needs editing".

Comment: To foreigners who don't have their on StackOverflow site, I suspect that "editing" may be a simpler word than "revision"

Comment: I don't like "on hold" all that much, but I'm not sure "needs editing" or "needs revision" is an improvement as it's simply wrong for a subset of closed questions. If somebody asks a question that does not fall in the "on topic but not reasonably answerable" categories (e.g. asking about hardware, math, or other things not in scope for SO) and thus cannot be fixed by editing, then the question does _not_ need editing. Editing would rather be detrimental for a number of reasons such as bumping a crap post and delaying autodeletion. This change would improve some cases but make others worse.

Comment: @l4mpi: which is why I suggested reason specific wordings (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298790/4136325)

Comment: Duplicates should still be marked with [duplicate], but for the other ones the actions required to reopen the question all involve editing: unclear - edit to clarify, too broad - edit to narrow scope, opinion based - edit to make objective, off topic - edit to match the scope of SO.

Comment: Of course, some questions are hopelessly unreopenable without making the question completely different (e.g. "How can I tell if a girl likes me?") but I would argue that those are worthy of not just closing, but deletion.

Comment: @PeterOlson that's exactly my point. Some off topic questions should be deleted instead of edited, yet the wording would imply that they need to be edited. Most of those questions are probably auto-deleted by the system due to being closed for n (was it 7 or 9?) days without an edit, thus editing is actively harmful as it delays deletion.

Comment: @l4mpi If the question asker is able to edit a bad question into something fitting, it should be reopened. Suppose, from the example I gave earlier, the asker left out some important details from the question "I have a social network graph with such and such scoring for 'node A likes B', what's the most efficient algorithm for (etc.)". Even though the original question was *really bad*, the user should know that he has a fair opportunity to whip it up into shape.

Comment: @PeterOlson I'm sorry, you don't seem to understand my point. I'll try a third time: of course some questions that are closed _can_ be improved, but as you've said yourself **others can never be made on topic for the site**. Those questions neither need editing nor revision - editing them is actively harmful as it delays autodeletion.

Comment: @l4mpi [The existing on hold system is already designed for the purpose of encouraging users to edit their questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497) which seems to indicate to me that there's no huge concern about users pointlessly editing their questions. By the way, I understood your argument, but I wanted to point out that it's not so obvious sometimes which questions are hopeless, and users should know that they have a chance to improve the question regardless of how awful it looks at first sight.

Comment: Along the lines of what @l4mpi was saying, I think we should use a different word other than "needs". *Needs* editing implies an obligation to improve the question, when it might be beyond help. I'd advocate for a more passive word that suggests one should help if they think the question is deserving and leave it alone otherwise. ("Awaiting" and "pending" seem to have been rejected already, and unfortunately I can't think of a word of the kind I'm describing off the top of my head.)

Answer (score 10):

The wording should be changed to "needs revision".

Comment: For me, this variant is better than others, because "reopen" votes can be given without any editing, and those voted to close might misunderstand the question, or a pending edit is already in place that'll clarify it to meet SE requirements while close votes already amass to the closure point. Also a revision by OP might make him find out that the question is either trivial, or stupid, or he was just unable to properly form a question and he'd get an answer mid-edit, thus a revision is needed on all normal questions, but an edit might not be required in all cases.

Comment: This sounds terrible to me. Probably "in need of a revision"?

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea of [@Thomas' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298790/4639281), but I don't think we need new terms when we have already agreed on terms for closure reasons. I propose we just append the close reason to the end of the title.

`[ Unclear ]`
`[ Too Broad ]`
`[ Duplicate ]`
`[ Off Topic ]`

I don't think there is any need to specify which `off topic` reason is used, as there is usually nothing the community can do about those questions.

Similarly, I think that `[ Primarily Opinion Based ]` could be lumped in with `[ Off Topic ]` because there is not very much that the community can do to make questions that were closed with this reason acceptable (and it is overly long).

Comment: No, I think we do need different terms. The close reason is the reason for closing, and we now need a term to tell the author what they need to do in order to get the question reopened.

Comment: All of the information that is necessary for the author to improve their question is in the banner underneath their post. From what I understand, this will help differentiate posts when searching, and will remove the confusing connotation that "On Hold" gives.

Comment: "Necessary" and "Desirable" are two different things.

Comment: I don't really understand what that comment is supposed to mean. What are you referring to?

Comment: You said "All of the information that is necessary". I distinguish between "necessary" and "desirable".

Comment: We could provide the users with a book, we could throw it at their head, it won't change the fact that most of the time they wont read it. As far as that goes I'm most interested in making it easier to find questions that can be fixed and ignore questions that cannot.

Comment: @TinyGiant IMO a closed question can only fixed by the asker. If a random user can fix it, it should've been fixed rather than closed.

Comment: @Dukeling It happens a lot that something may be unclear for the majority, but someone else may be able to better understand and clarify the question. For too broad, it can be narrowed down by the community if there is a significant enough interest in the answer, and the OP may roll back the edit if it deviated to far from the original intent. Duplicates can be useful as signposts so can be left alone, but off topic questions labeled as such would then be easier to ignore.

Answer (score -10):

<sub>I liked to vote for [jmac's version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298683/should-we-change-on-hold-to-needs-revision-or-something-similar/298788#comment217264_298683), but it wasn't yet posted as answer, so here it is:</sub>

The wording should be changed to "awaiting improvement".

Answer (score -11):

An alternate option in the spirit of not using big words:

"needs fixing"

Comment: So many downvotes, so little explanation... Is this really that much worse than "needs editing" or does my reference to not using big words sound offensive (many users speak English as a 2nd or 3rd language, so using big words should generally be discouraged)? Or is it just because I was late?

Comment: I didn't vote on this one, but I don't particularly like it because "needs fixing" seems ever-so-slightly antagonistic, since it implies the question is currently broken rather than simply unrevised or unimproved.

Comment: Have an upvote. No answer here bothers to explain what they see wrong in "On Hold" and how their suggestion rectifies it, but I prefer this wording above the others'.

Comment: I don't feel that "needs fixing" maintains the same rapport the site has with the users. The message needs to mesh into the existing communication that the site has with the users.

Answer (score -15):

Why don't we give this to [the experts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257659/a-better-phrase-for-on-hold-in-the-context-of-stack-exchange)?

If this is a question of English diction, persuasion, rhetoric, or verbal concision, etc. there's a community for that.

---

**Result:**

> Needs Improvement

Comment: Not sure - experts in English aren't necessarily experts in what a high-traffic community like SO (with its loads of non-native English speakers) may need.

Comment: @Pekka웃 You're probably right, but it can't harm to ask...

Comment: LOL ! That question was ***put on hold** as primarily opinion-based*

Comment: @joaquin Oh the irony...

Comment: @Pekka웃 I did clarify that it should not be verbose in my requirements.

Answer (score -18):

I think "pending revision" would be quite fitting.

Comment: It might be understood as: "don't bother fixing this because someone already submitted an edit that is currently pending" or "this question is currently pending - we'll get to it soon (no action required from your side)", neither of which is desirable.

Answer (score -29):

The wording should remain as "on hold".

Comment: Any particular reasoning as to why?

Comment: @Khalos I made three posts with different alternatives just so that people can vote based on their preference.

Comment: Oops! Sorry I didn't notice they were all you. I was just curious as to what the argument would be for this alternative.

Comment: Wouldn't people just downvote the question if they think the wording should stay as is?

Comment: Sure, but it's nice to have all the options in a parallel format. Also, some people don't have the rep to see the number of downvotes on the question.